# Remove NA elements from column of vectors using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, pmap

I am trying to merge columns into one column, I've combined them using `pmap`.

Some columns have NAs, I'd like to remove the NAs from the combined column `col_comb` and leave the other values.

```r
df = tribble(~id, ~col1, ~col2, ~col3,
             1, "a", "b", "c",
             2, "a", NA, "c",
             3, "a", NA, NA,
             4, NA, NA, NA)
df = df %>% 
  mutate(col_comb = pmap(list(col1,col2,col3), c))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify a lambda function to do this

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 <- df %>% 
    mutate(col_comb = pmap(select(., starts_with('col')), 
             ~  as.character(na.omit(c(...)))))
```

-output

```
df1$col_comb
#[[1]]
#[1] "a" "b" "c"

#[[2]]
#[1] "a" "c"

#[[3]]
#[1] "a"

#[[4]]
#character(0)
```

---

Or another option is `c_across` with `rowwise`

```
df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(col_comb = list(na.omit(c_across(-id)))) %>% 
  ungroup
```

Comment: Thank you! .. You know what, I was waiting for you when I wrote this and I was sure you will answer it :)

That works perfectly, and I can apply list operations `length`, `first`, etc.